# Integrate an array in an existing function

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to install a plugin i found but the explications are not good.

The goal is to use multiple catégories in the wordpress plugin.

It tells me to use this code to display it :

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'get_slidervilla_slider_taxonomy' ) ){ get_slidervilla_slider_taxonomy('slider=roster&taxonomy=category&term=uncategorized&set=1');
}
?>
```

But if i want to use multiple catégories i have to add that :

```
'term' => array( 'social-media', 'news' )
```

But i don't know how or where ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_slidervilla_slider_taxonomy' ) ) {
    $term = array( 'social-media', 'news' );
    $args=array(
         'slider'=>'thumbel',
         'post_type'=>'post', 
         'taxonomy'=>'category',
         'term'=> $term, //pass in the $term array
         'set'=>'', 
         'offset'=>0 
    );
    get_slidervilla_slider_taxonomy($args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a comma between names.

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'get_slidervilla_slider_taxonomy' ) ){ get_slidervilla_slider_taxonomy('slider=roster&taxonomy=category&term=social-media,news&set=1');
}
?>
```

Thanks.